# How to enable autopopup suggestion list for html-files in PyCharm 2016

Tags: html, autocomplete, pycharm, code-completion, jetbrains-ide

I bought the Pro Version of PyCharm (2016.3.2).

How can I activate the autopopup suggestion list for autocompletion for html-snippets?

It is working for all other file types like .py .js. and .css but not in .html files.

I have to press `CMD+J` or `TAB` to get the list, but I want it to popup with typing the first character like with the other files.

Preferences are setup correct I think:

[image: Settings: Code Completion]

Especially I would like to show up my own Live-Templates. Who can give an advice?

Comment: 1) Try with `Case sensitive completion` set to `None`; 2) `Help | Find Action...`, type `registry` and activate that found action -- once Registry window is shown - locate `show.live.templates.in.completion` -- it should be enabled. **P.S.** But TBH -- if it works in other files then it should work the same in .html files as well.

Comment: 1) It has no effect
2) It is enabled

This is strange. When I am in an html file and press "_a_" I would expect to see ´<a href=""></a>` But I have to press "_a_" and the CMD+J and then TAB to execute. Is this normal behavior in PyCharm or should I report a bug?

Comment: Pressing `a[TAB]` is absolutely normal (no real need for `Cmd+J`, unless you wish to specify that this must be a Live Template) -- it will expand `a` Emmet abbreviation/Live Template into final text (all standard/fixed Emmet abbreviations are handled via Live Templates).

Comment: Plus ... I forgot that you are in HTML context .. where `a` is treated as just a plain text (look at this: how IDE should know if you about to type `a` (as in `a dog` text) or if this mean to be `<a>` tag). If IDE will invoke code completion popup for every letter .. it will not be possible to type in HTML/XML context. Thing is: HTML/XML is a "random" mix of plain text and tags .. as compared to more "strict" JS/CSS (I know 00 not the best comparison/explanation but better than nothing)

Comment: If you want to see code completion popup for `a` and see live templates and other stuff (HTML tags) -- consider typing `<a`. For Live Templates -- just press the expand key (`Tab` in your case) after entering unique abbreviation of that Live Template. If you forgot exact abbreviation -- use `Ctrl+Space` (Windows/Linux shortcut; general code completion) or `Cmd+J` (Live Templates only) and then make you choice there. P.S. You may delete your incomplete comments

Comment: I understand the argument. But when using editors like sublime text or VS Code etc. they do exactly that, even in HTML context. But If this is normal behavior in PyCharm I have to accept that. Thanks for your quick explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is correct for HTML/XML context.

Imagine this HTML code:

```
<p>a</p>
```

How IDE should know *for sure* what are you about to type here (after typing initial `a` letter):

- maybe it will be word `apple`?
- or maybe `a dog`?
- or maybe you actually want enter `<a>` tag here?

If code completion would popup here .. I would abandon such IDE straight away -- otherwise how I suppose to type plain text here .. considering that I will see popup window almost all the time?

So...

- if you wish to see code completion at this point (plain text context) you will have to invoke code completion popup manually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> (or whatever you have there for `Code | Completion | Basic`) after typing `a`.
- for list of Live Templates alone, pressing <kbd>Cmd + J</kbd> (`Code | Insert Live Template`) is required.
- for quicker Live Template/Emmet invocation (if you know **exact** Live Template abbreviation) -- just press expand key (<kbd>Tab</kbd> by default in most OS/Keymaps) .. so `a[Tab]` will convert that into desired `<a href=""></a>` expanded text.

Comment: This is very logical and the perfect answer. Thank you very much. :)